# GetDBSet using IQueryable object - performance issue? - Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have few db table names that I need to query to get a count of rows from each one of them. Since I'm unaware of the number of tables and what table names are being requested, I have written for each loop to query each table by getting DBSet and implemented IQueryable object.

```
public static IQueryable<object> Set (this DbContext _context, Type t)
        {
            return (IQueryable<object>)_context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(_context, null);
        }
```

```
var obj = Set(_dbContext, MyCustomType);

int Count = obj.Select(pItem=>pItem).ToList().Where(pItem=>pItem.ID = ID).Count()
```

since "obj" is IQueryable object, could **obj.Select(pItem=>pItem).ToList()** cause performance issue because we are getting large data to a memory object? What could be the efficient way to handle this scenario?

If I had to query a single table, wouldn't we do the same way, like:

```
int Count = _dbcontext.Set<TableName>.ToList().Where(pItem=>pItem.ID= ID).Count()

Or

int Count = _dbcontext.TableName.ToList().Where(pItem=>pItem.ID= ID).Count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `cast IQueryable<object> type to specific List<MyCustomType> type`, then you can use select and where function to return what you need.

```
 var obj = _dbContext.Set(typeof(MyCustomType));
 int count = obj.Select(pItem => pItem).ToList().Cast<MyCustomType>().Where(pItem => pItem.ID == ID).Count();
```